# SQLPS: What's the syntax to load data to a table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

Since SQLPS essentially treats database tables like files, how would you load a directory list for example in to a table using only SQLPS?

What's the syntax to load data without using an external helper like BCP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Server provider does not support CRUD operations against the data stored in tables. Instead you would need to use the invoke-sqlcmd cmdlet or .NET code. This is bit hacky, here's one way to load a directory listing into a SQL table:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\WIN7BOOT\SQL1\Databases\hsg> dir e:\sw | foreach {invoke-sqlcmd -query "insert dirlist values ('$($_.name)', $(if ($_.length) {$_.length} else {0}), '$($_.lastwritetime)', $($_.PSIsContainer -as [int]))"}
```

One thing SQL provider does is allow you to omit the serverinstance and database parameters from invoke-sqlcmd. The current server and database is assumed.